# Desktop background after logging in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, python, purge

I am new to ubuntu and I don't know what to do in this problem. I wanted to completely uninstall python so i did

```
sudo get-apt purge python
```

in between this process I closed the terminal as I saw that all programs are being uninstalled. Now after reboot i can only see a wallpaper at the background nothing else. NO dashboard no graphics.
I have researched on few webpages but I couldn't find the related solution
I dont know which important graphics software i uninstalled or else

I have tried using

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

but it unables to fetch the files from **mc.archive.ubuntu**

Comment: is it a fresh install? Then I would just reinstall again and don't even try to fix it, it might be the fastest way anyway...

Comment: No it is not fresh install

Comment: Still install from fresh will be the fastest and easiest solution, since you can't even connect to a software source. boot up a live usb/cd and backup your files if you need to and install from scratch. Do it!

Comment: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop worked...many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Ubuntu desktop is mainly based on Python programs. If you uninstall a requirement, apt-get will remove all program that have python as requirement (something like 90% of Ubuntu desktop).

If you still have access to bash, try the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get check
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
outputs connecting to mc.archive and stays at 0% no address associated with hostname

Comment: This is a problem with ip address that apt-get is using. Fixng this issue via command line seems a difficult problem

Comment: Click the checkbox on the top left corner of my answer then ;) . And remember : never, ever, purge without checking first what will be removed.